# How to extract various Thresholds of Chl-a pixels in ArcGIS in bulk?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, extract

I have 17 years worth of Chl-a data from January to December in raster format and now I just want to just look at amounts from 10-30 mg/m3 of Chl-a data. Can I extract just this data from the image, keeping the shapefile and can I do it in bulk with file names being differientiated as well?